# Gradle finds wrong JAVA_HOME even though it's correctly set ubuntu 13.10

Tags: java, gradle

I have just installed gradle from the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

After finishing am trying to run the command

```
gradle -v
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

When I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

So that's the correct path
I edited my bashrc file
added the following lines

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
export JAVA_HOME
```

I still get the same error when I run `gradle -v`

Comment: Where is java installed? How did you installed it?

Answer (score 6):

This sort of question was also [answered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22309017/1265245).  Turns out that there is an `export` in `/usr/bin/gradle` that probably shouldn't be there.

One solution is to comment out that `export` line.  Another solution is to use [a PPA that has a different/newer Gradle](http://wtanaka.com/node/8079).

Comment: I tried creating a dynamic symbolic link in my .bash_profile  (because I use Jenv on Mac)  at  `ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/default-java $JAVA_HOME`  and it did not resolve the issue for me.  Would rather not edit my Gradle distro executor, but i guess if I have to...

Answer (score 3):

You have incorrectly set your `JAVA_HOME` variable. It shouldn't be pointing to the jre but to the jdk.

Set your `JAVA_HOME` variable to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`.

Comment: Not working for me...I got the latest gradle and moreover my JAVA_HOME is /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with the **gradle** which is **appending** /bin/java `JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"` to your **JAVA_HOME** path in its scripts.
so go to your `gradle-3.3/bin` location of your gradle scripts and edit the gradle file using gedit.

```
    if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
        # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
    if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
        die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
```

this is the code snippet which is appending the java path hence results in an invalid path since you have already included **/bin/java** in your **JAVA_HOME**. so either change it here or remove the */bin/java* from your *JAVA_HOME*  path variable from the **/etc/environment**.
I have removed the */bin/java* from the *JAVA_HOME* path and it worked fine for me.